# How to rotate an image which is retrieved by ashx handler

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have an image which is returned from MySql. Its datatype is image in Mysql. I handle the image with ashx. 
the code below show my ashx file.

```
string imageID = context.Request.QueryString["imageID"];
using(SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(portalConnectionString))
{
    objConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand fetchTaskImageCMD = new SqlCommand("fetch_task_image", objConnection);
    fetchTaskImageCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    fetchTaskImageCMD.Parameters.Add("@IMAGE_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = imageID;

    try
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = fetchTaskImageCMD.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();

        byte[] bufferImg = (Byte[])dr[0];

        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bufferImg, 0, bufferImg.Length);
    }

    catch
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Image Handler Failed : /DesktopModules/ImageHandler.ashx");
    }

    objConnection.Close();
}
```

And the code below is showing how I am calling my ashx file from my asp.net code behind class in c#.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   FetchedImage.ImageUrl = "/DesktopModules/ImageHandler.ashx?imageType=" + imageType + "&imageID=" + imageID;
}
```

My question is how I am going to rotate this image and save back to database,then.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate it and save it back to the database, use GDI+ on the server instead of streaming it back to the client.

System.Drawing.Image can be instantiated from a byte array, and from that you can use GDI+ methods to rotate the image, extract a byte array from the rotated image and save that.

Let me know if you need an example, but googling System.Drawing.Image will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I had figured out a way of which allowing me to rotate the image by RotateFlipType and convert back to Byte array, then save back to database all in ashx file. However, I found this is really slow because it requires post back each time I rotate the image. I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this such as rotating the image on client side, only save it if I click save button.

Comment: I tried jquery first.I have to switch to bitmap instead of jquery because the javascript doesn't rotate the "actual" image file.

Comment: You're probably stuck with the GDI option then mate